# Why is Express not serving up my static files?

Tags: node.js, express

URL: http://example.com:8080/js/file.js

```
var express = require('express');
app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.listen(8080);
```

**Directory Structure**

```
/

index.js (loaded node file)
public (folder)
----js (folder)
    ----file.js (requested file)
```

Error: Cannot GET /js/file.js

Comment: although you should provide full path  your code is working on my machine, try app.use(express.logger('dev')); and see the output of console in which node.js is running the file

Answer (score 2):

Provide the full path to the directory:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to set up something like what is described in this tutorial

http://www.mfranc.com/node-js/node-js-simple-web-server-with-express/

```
/* serves all the static files */
app.get(/^(.+)$/, function(req, res){ 
    console.log('static file request : ' + req.params);
    res.sendfile( __dirname + req.params[0]); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of express are you using? For me, using 3.4.0, the following didn't work:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

but this did:

```
app.use("/public", express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Not sure if its version specific, but usign the first syntax if was failing with the same Error: Cannot get XXX error